# How To Fix Auto Login In Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

How To Fix Auto login When I go to this URL like this: `127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1` When I see If Someone go to that URL so Django login him without password and username

**ERROR:**
How To Fix Auto Login In Django

You Can See The Gif For More Details:

[image]

**Views.py**

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    model = user_register_model()
    return render(request,'profile_detail_view.html',{'user':user,'model':model,})
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('accounts/signup/', views.user_reg,name='register'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>',views.profile_detail,name='profile'),

]
```

Here is my **Base.html**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

  {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="nav-item">

      <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'register' %}"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp; Sign up Free</a>
    </li>    
    <li class="nav-item">

      <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'login' %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Login</a>
    </li>

  {% else %}
    <li class="nav-item">

      <a class="nav-link navaour" href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">

     <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Here is my **profile_detail_view.html**

```
<div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-5">
                                                <label style="font-weight:bold;">Full Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8 col-6">
                                                {{user.username}}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Any Help Appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: I think superuser is logged in.

Comment: @sandeep No I Refresh and Logout an then try again i get this error again

Comment: @sandeep if i again to home page the logout button disappear

Comment: use "{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}". you missed request

Comment: @sandeep Thanks Please Give Me Answer So I Can Accept And Up vote You!

Comment: it's okay...happy to help. good luck

Comment: @sandeep Please give Answer So I Can Up Vote You Because You Help Me I Also Need To Help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `{% if not user.is_authenticated %}` with `{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}` in your template. You missed **request**.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use @login_required before the def in views.py and importing library 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

This will help in blocking those views of url for the users who aren't logged in.